# Lexing and include directive with ocamllex

Tags: ocaml, lex, ocamllex

I'm making a compiler for a C-like language that has to support #include directive (only in the beginning of the file)

A simple but inelegant approach would be to create a subprogram that finds every occurrence of the directive, and substitutes with the corresponding file in a new temporary file.

Now that is not nice at all. So i tried the following:

```
lexer = parse
    | "#include \""   ( [^'"' '\n']* as filename) '"'
    { lexer (Lexing.from_channel (open_in filename)) ; lexer lexbuf }
```

the idea was the following: whenever you find an include, open a new channel using the given filename, and call recursively the "lexer" rule on that channel. After that, continue with the current state of your lexing-buffer and continue the lexing.

The problem is, it never worked.

i have also seen that it's possible to make a refiller when the buffer lexbuf has reached eof. But i failed to find more info. That gave me an idea of changing the above code to the following:

```
lexer = parse
    | "#include \""   ( [^'"' '\n']* as filename) '"'
    { addCurrentLexBufToAStack lexbuf ;lexer (Lexing.from_channel    (open_in filename)); }
```

and in the refiller, you would continue from the head of the stack

but seems very ambitious to work.

Any ideas?

P.s. The lexer (and parsing too) is called from another module (let's call it Main.ml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, aren't you a bit confused about lexing and parsing ?

What I see is that :

> If my lexeme is #include *ident* I want to **parse** what's in the
>   file pointed by  *ident* and add it.

You are then confusing **parsing** and **lexing**

You could write something like this : (it's a small program but it works ;-))

### ast.mli

```
type operation = 
 | Plus of operation * operation 
 | Minus of operation * operation
 | Int of int

type prog = string list * operation list
```

### lexer.mll

```
{
  open Parser
  open Lexing
  open Ast

  let current_pos b =
    lexeme_start_p b,
    lexeme_end_p b

}

let newline = '\n'
let space = [' ' '\t' '\r']

let digit = ['0' - '9']
let integer = digit+

rule token = parse
| newline { token lexbuf}
| space+ { token lexbuf}
| "#include \""   ( [^'"' '\n']* as filename) '"' { INCLUDE filename } 
| integer as i { INTEGER (int_of_string i) }
| "+" { PLUSI }
| "-" { MINUSI }
| ";" { SC }
| "main" { MAIN }
| eof
    { EOF }
```

### parser.mly

```
%{

  open Ast

%}

%token <string> INCLUDE
%token EOF SC
%token PLUSI 
%token MINUSI
%token MAIN
%token <int> INTEGER

%left PLUSI MINUSI

%start <Ast.prog> prog

%%

prog:
include_list MAIN operations EOF { ($1, $3) }

include_list:
| { [] }
| INCLUDE include_list { $1 :: $2 }

operation:
| operation PLUSI operation { Plus ($1, $3) }
| operation MINUSI operation { Minus ($1, $3) }
| INTEGER { Int $1 }

operations:
| operation { [$1] }
| operation SC operations { $1 :: $3 }
```

So, as you can see, when I parse I remember the filenames I have to parse and

### main.ml

```
open Lexing
open Ast

let rec print_op fmt op =
  match op with
    | Plus (op1, op2) ->
      Format.fprintf fmt "(%a + %a)"
        print_op op1 print_op op2
    | Minus (op1, op2) ->
      Format.fprintf fmt "(%a - %a)"
        print_op op1 print_op op2
    | Int i -> Format.fprintf fmt "%d" i

let rec read_includes fl =
  List.fold_left (fun acc f ->
    let c = open_in f in
    let lb = Lexing.from_channel c in
    let fl, p = Parser.prog Lexer.token lb in
    close_in c;
    let acc' = read_includes fl in
    acc' @ p
  ) [] fl

let () =
  try
    let p = read_includes [Sys.argv.(1)] in
    List.iter (Format.eprintf "%a@." print_op) p
  with _ -> Format.eprintf "Bad Boy !@."
```

Which means that when I finished parsing the first file I parse the files included.

The most important thing is your confusion about lexing (which is the dumbest thing in a compiler, you just ask "What is the next token that you see ?" and he answers "I see `#include "filename"`" and the parser which is not that dumb and says "Hey, the lexer saw `#include "filename"` so I will keep in mind this filename because I may need it and I will keep going.

And if I have these three files :

### file1

```
#include "file2"
main 
6; 7
```

### file2

```
#include "file3"
main 
4; 5
```

### file3

```
main 
1; 2; 3
```

If I call `./compile file1` I have the output `1 2 3 4 5 6` which is what I want. ;-)

### [EDIT]

New version with the lexer handling the includes :

### ast.mli

```
type operation = 
  | Plus of operation * operation 
  | Minus of operation * operation
  | Int of int

type prog = operation list
```

### lexer.mll

```
{
  open Parser
  let fset = Hashtbl.create 17
  (* set keeping all the filenames *)
}

let newline = '\n'
let space = [' ' '\t' '\r']

let digit = ['0' - '9']
let integer = digit+

rule token = parse
| newline { token lexbuf}
| space+ { token lexbuf}
| "#include \""   ( [^'"' '\n']* as filename) '"' 
    { if Hashtbl.mem fset filename then
        raise Exit
      else 
        let c = open_in filename in
        Hashtbl.add fset filename ();
        let lb = Lexing.from_channel c in
        let p = Parser.prog token lb in
        INCLUDE p
    }
| integer as i { INTEGER (int_of_string i) }
| "+" { PLUSI }
| "-" { MINUSI }
| ";" { SC }
| "main" { MAIN }
| eof
    { EOF }
```

### parser.mly

```
%{

  open Ast

%}

%token <Ast.prog> INCLUDE
%token EOF SC
%token PLUSI 
%token MINUSI
%token MAIN
%token <int> INTEGER

%left PLUSI MINUSI

%start <Ast.prog> prog

%%

prog:
include_list MAIN operations EOF { List.rev_append (List.rev $1) $3  }

include_list:
| { [] }
| INCLUDE include_list { List.rev_append (List.rev $1) $2 }

operation:
| operation PLUSI operation { Plus ($1, $3) }
| operation MINUSI operation { Minus ($1, $3) }
| INTEGER { Int $1 }

operations:
| operation { [$1] }
| operation SC operations { $1 :: $3 }
```

### main.ml

```
open Lexing
open Ast

let rec print_op fmt op =
  match op with
    | Plus (op1, op2) ->
      Format.fprintf fmt "(%a + %a)"
        print_op op1 print_op op2
    | Minus (op1, op2) ->
      Format.fprintf fmt "(%a - %a)"
        print_op op1 print_op op2
    | Int i -> Format.fprintf fmt "%d" i

let () =
  try
    let c = open_in Sys.argv.(1) in
    let lb = Lexing.from_channel c in
    let p = Parser.prog Lexer.token lb in
    close_in c;
    List.iter (Format.eprintf "%a@." print_op) p
  with _ -> Format.eprintf "Bad Boy !@."
```

So, in the lexer, when I see a `#include filename` I call immediately the Parser on the file linked by `filename` and returns the `Ast.prog` parsed to the previous call of parsing.

I hope it's all clear for you ;-)

### [SECOND EDIT]

I can't let this code like this, I edited it to avoid include loops (in lexer.mll) ;-)

Comment: thank you for your interesting answer  (it made a few things clear to me) and your time! What you are saying does make sense, but we were instructed (this is part of a course) to do this in the **lexer** and specifically: when our lexer finds an include directive, it should stop 'lexing' the current file, and continue from the included file (and this could be nested)

Comment: Well, I'm working on it, then, because I don't want to work, today !

Comment: @Lhooq Shouldn't we use `close_in` in the `read_includes` function?

Comment: @AntonTrunov Yes, we should, but I'm dirty !

Comment: @AntonTrunov But since I'm not stubborn I edited my code ;-)